# Get rid of grey background in python matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I get rid of the grey background in the plot below made using foll command in python matplotlib

```
ax.bar(x_axis,bar_val,yerr=err_val,linewidth=0,width=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: that's not your whole script -- matplotlib looks nothing like that by default. what else are you doing? are you importing the `seaborn` package? do you have a matplotlibrc file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, I should point out that the grey background is not the default for matplotlib. Are you using something like seaborn, which (inappropriately, in my opinion) messes with matplotlib's defaults by default whenever you import it?

As I'm assuming ax is already your axis, you can just do:

```
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

Comment: ahh,yes! I am using seaborn. this is very helpful. ty!

Comment: aesthetics are a primary goal of seaborn. but you can do `import seaborn.apionly as sns` if you don't want the figure aesthetics modified.

Comment: and totally agree, re the grey background. seaborn is beautiful otherwise

Comment: use `seaborn.set_style` to chose from the various options seaborn provides. I prefer `seaborn.set_style('ticks')` myself

Answer (score 15):

The `set_axis_bgcolor` function was deprecated in version 2.0. Use `set_facecolor` instead. Your code would be:

```
 ax.set_facecolor('white')
```